# AVPlayerViewController audio continues playing in background after dismissal

Tags: swift, swiftui

My goal is to:

1. Record a video
2. Show it in a view and play it on a loop
3. Dismiss it from the view
4. Repeat with a **new** video

Problem:

Steps 1-3 work. However, the audio continues playing in the background after I toggle `camera.showMoviePreview` to `false`

Here is the view in which I render the video:

```
if camera.showMoviePreview {
                   
      CustomVideoPlayer(url: camera.previewURL)                    
                
}
```

Here is my `AVPlayerViewController`

```
struct CustomVideoPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    ///URL of the video
    var url:URL?

    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        

        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        let playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper!

        
        let url: URL = url!
        let player1 = AVPlayer(url: url)
        
        player1.preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideoPlayback = true
        player1.allowsExternalPlayback = true
        
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        
        controller.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        controller.player = player1
        controller.player?.play()
        

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        let player = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: playerItem)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: controller.player?.currentItem, queue: .main)
                   {  _ in
                       controller.player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                       controller.player?.play()
                   }

        return controller
    }
    
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

I believe the audio continues playing because I am not unmounting the `AVPlayerViewController`, but I'm not sure the proper way to do so

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can stop video in "onDisapear" method,

1, define AVPlayer property in the class not in the makeUIViewController.

2, define CustomVideoPlayer(url: camera.previewURL) as a view like:

```
var videoPlayer: some View{
    CustomVideoPlayer(url: camera.previewURL)
}
```

3, use int like:

```
if camera.showMoviePreview {
   videoPlayer
       .onDisappear {
           camera.videoPlayer.pause()
       }
}
```